# How do I select specific JSON value to create a string?

Tags: php, json, laravel-5.3

I have the below JSON output:

```
  "data" => "[
                 {"month":2,"total_payments":"720.00"},
                 {"month":3,"total_payments":"500.00"}
            ]"
```

I am struggling for the syntax to select a specific value to create a string from. For example I want to be able to **output**:

```
$month = ["2", "3"]
$total_payments = ["720", "500"]
```

So far I have this code but not working.

`<?php  echo $data->month?>`

Comment: did you decode the json string first?

Comment: I see syntax errors in your json.

Comment: I have used the toJson() method in laravel which returns 
array:1 [▼
  "data" => "[{"month":2,"total_payments":"720.00"},{"month":3,"total_payments":"500.00"}]"
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop over your array and fetch the informations you want. For example :

```
$months = array();
$total_payments = array();
foreach($datas['data'] as $data) {
    $months[] = $data->month;
    $total_payments[] = $data->total_payments;
}
```

Comment: No, I was saying that `"data" => "[{"month"` is a syntax error. Use `'` to wrap that json.